# Is it accepted to fit model with standardized data and predict on non-standardized data?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, prediction, model, standardization

If you standardize your training data, then can it work on unstandardized data during predictions accurately?

Many algorithms require the feature data to be standardized and **I am wondering how/why/if this works when using non-standardized data to predict on if the model was fit with standardized data?**

For example, what if you only had a single observation (or a few) you wanted predict using the model? You wouldn't be able to standardize the data.

I'm following this tutorial here by Sebastian Raschka and it got me thinking about the above questions:
http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_about_feature_scaling.html#about-standardization

[image]

Comment: Please search our site for related threads: http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=prediction+standardize+training .  The duplicate showed up as one of the top hits.

Comment: Definitely a similar question but there wasn't an answer on it.  Do you have any suggestions on what to do in a situation like this where there is a similar question that is unanswered?